# Numpy help on calculation of Angular speed of rotational body

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rotation, scipy

I am trying to calculate Angular speed of rotational object. From the data, I have the angle of the object at each time interval. Eg.

> Numpy Array =[5,85,185,270,355,10,75, 170, 250,345, 25, ...]

for clockwise rotation and similarly for

> counter clockwise rotation Numpy Array = [25, 345, 250, 170, 75, 10,
>   355, 270, 185, 85, 5, ...].

So when I try to calculate the difference between the angle, for a range of 0 to 360 and vice versa I can use numpy.diff() which works good in this case.

When when I happen to reach difference from 360 to 0 or for eg. as shown in fig. A, from 355 degree to 5 degree, I cannot use numpy.diff() anymore. 
I have to use a conditional statement like:

```
        if ang[i+1]>280 and theta<80:
            new_theta=-1*((theta-ang[i+1])%360)
```

And similarly when the rotational motion is in counter clockwise direction, I use a condition similar to above to get the difference in angle (dTheta):

```
    elif ang[i+1]<80 and theta>280:
        new_theta=360%(theta-ang[i+1])
```

[image: Fig. A shows rotating object in clockwise direction and Fig. B shows counter clockwise rotation.]

And for the general when the angle is neither close to the limit i.e. 0 or 360.

```
new_theta=ang[i+1]-theta
```

So is there a better way of Computing the limits which provide better results fast and efficiently?

I am not able to handle the range limitation. And I wasn't sure if `scipy norm` could have helped here.

Any suggestion for the betterment of the problem is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: you'll have to make some assumptions about maximum angular velocity, because it's possible that your object could spin 350 degrees in one time step. If it can't I would say that you should calculate the differences, then if most of them are positive, correct the negative ones accordingly or vica versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the rotation is always in one direction, you can calculate the diff and then go through and fix the errors.  So, for example:

```
>>> arr = np.array([5,85,185,270,355,10,75, 170, 250,345, 25])
>>> darr = np.diff(arr)
>>> print(darr)
[  80  100   85   85 -345   65   95   80   95 -320]
>>> darr[darr<0] += 360
[ 80 100  85  85  15  65  95  80  95  40]
```

This will likely be the fastest approach.

Another approach would be to use the `numpy.unwrap`, which tries to figure out where you go around a circle.  However, it only works with radians, so you need to convert it to radians, unwrap, then convert it to degrees:

```
>>> warr = np.rad2deg(np.unwrap(np.deg2rad(arr)))
>>> print(warr)
[   5.   85.  185.  270.  355.  370.  435.  530.  610.  705.  745.]
>>> dwarr = np.diff(warr)
>>> print(dwarr)
[  80.  100.   85.   85.   15.   65.   95.   80.   95.   40.]
```

In this toy example it gives the same results, but it won't always, because it doesn't assume that the rotation is in a particular direction.  This means it is more likely to make mistakes if the rotation is always in the same direction than the simple approach I gave before.

If you can't assume the rotation is always in a particular direction, then there is no good objective way to do this.  `np.unwrap` is probably your best bet, but it is just guessing.  There is no definitive way to tell a small jump in one direction from a large jump in the other direction.

Comment: Sorry, I think I forgot to add that the direction is not particular. But, yes, unwrap worked very well. The object may hit something and again might go anticlockwise.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your measurements to radians and use [`np.unwrap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html) before using `np.diff`.

For example, here's your data, in degrees:

```
In [93]: d = np.array([5, 85, 185, 270, 355, 10, 75, 170, 250, 345, 25])
```

Convert to radians:

```
In [94]: theta = (np.pi/180) * d

In [95]: theta
Out[95]: 
array([ 0.08726646,  1.48352986,  3.22885912,  4.71238898,  6.19591884,
        0.17453293,  1.30899694,  2.96705973,  4.36332313,  6.02138592,
        0.43633231])
```

Unwrap:

```
In [96]: u = np.unwrap(theta)

In [97]: u
Out[97]: 
array([  0.08726646,   1.48352986,   3.22885912,   4.71238898,
         6.19591884,   6.45771823,   7.59218225,   9.25024504,
        10.64650844,  12.30457123,  13.00270293])
```

Compute the differences:

```
In [98]: delta_theta = np.diff(u)

In [99]: delta_theta
Out[99]: 
array([ 1.3962634 ,  1.74532925,  1.48352986,  1.48352986,  0.26179939,
        1.13446401,  1.65806279,  1.3962634 ,  1.65806279,  0.6981317 ])
```

Convert back to degrees:

```
In [100]: delta_degrees = (180/np.pi) * delta_theta

In [101]: delta_degrees
Out[101]: array([ 80., 100.,  85.,  85.,  15.,  65.,  95.,  80.,  95.,  40.])
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. This worked flawless as explained. But I haven't yet received the data in which there might be small to and fro rotation which might cause problem as stated by @TheBlackCat in his last paragraph. Would it cause the problem?

Comment: If you are sampling the angle frequently enough so that you know the object will not rotate more than 180 degrees (either way) between samples, this should work fine.  If you can't guarantee that, then without more information, there is ambiguity in the measurement (e.g. +190 degrees is the same as -170 degrees).

Comment: Well, even though I am not sure, that in a given time frame my object rotates more than 180 degree, I found a spike in data. I am not sure if that is due to a missing point, but a spike can be hazardous.